# Photoshop image resize looks terrible for an unknown reason

Tags: photoshop

Original image file

http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2014/173/1/7/4_charmander_by_monstermmorpg-d7ngugj.png

Resized with paint.net 3.5.11

http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2014/173/5/6/paint_net_resize_by_monstermmorpg-d7nguje.png

Resized with photoshop cs 6 13.0 x64 and quality is terrible

http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2014/173/9/c/photoshop_resize_by_monstermmorpg-d7nguqn.png

Any idea why and any idea how to solve this very annoying problem ? I tried all re-sampling options nothing works

Thank you

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [graphic design](http://graphicdesign.stackaexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is probably because it is indexed colour, which gives is a limited palette.

Go to Image - Mode - RGB Color

When it is RGB, it should resize fine.

Comment: wow it fixed. so how can i apply this at batch mode ? you know from File > Scripts > image processor. ty very much

Comment: There's probably other ways, but you can use the actions and record converting the mode as one of its steps.  The image processor seems to allow you to run an action. (batch - automate may be a better tool, as the image processor doesn't appear to handle pngs.)

Comment: yes i did batch change mode ty

Comment: can we say best mode is RGB ?

Comment: The best format depends on an individual image.  Indexed colour can often create a smaller image, certainly for graphics with not many colours.  Graphics can look sharper with indexed colour.  Photos usually look terrible indexed, but I think you'd then choose between CYMK for print or RGB for monitor.  They all have their strengths.